# Any tool to "bird-eye view" HTML structure of a web page?

Tags: html, editor, atom-editor

I am dissecting HTML emails to learn HTML patterns for layout.

I see lots of nesting elements such as `div>table>tbody>tr>div>table>tbody>tr.`

Are there any packages for Atom to obtain a bird eye view of HTML tags?

Say they hide the contents inside the tags, so we can quickly see the pattern of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, [`html-outliner`](https://atom.io/packages/html-outliner) appears to be what you're looking for. However, the output didn't seem very useful to me when I tried it.

In general, I recommend [`atom-beautify`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) for working with HTML. It will properly indent nested HTML tags which can be an immense help when trying to discern the pattern of the tags, as you say.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander!

Comment: Thanks, Alexander! I found out that I can do the "birdeye view" with Chrome  Inspect Tool.  Toggle nested elements to discover the layout structure. Apparently, Atom Editor also has something similar but not as visually satisfying. 

I would try out html-outliner